# How to extract my typing data from 10fastfingers?

Tags: python, web-scraping

So, I am using the website 10fastfingers.com and I want to use Python web scraping to extract my typing data from the website.

https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english/
This is the website's link.
Here you go and type out the words until the timer expires. And, then it gets you the score. The problem is that when I try to use requests or bs4 module to extract my typing data. It brings to the original website rather than the website I have after I filled the form.

The original website looks like this:

[original website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSA6Y.png)

And, after I do my typing test, it looks like this:

[after doing typing test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COR72.png)

Now, I want to extract the data from the second website, that is, my typing speed and accuracy.
How would I do this?

I am proficient in python, pandas and numpy but not so much in web scraping.

Answer (score 1):

The site uses Ajax calls to send user keystroke data and receive results. This example sends some sample data and parses the result:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://10fastfingers.com/speedtests/auswertung"
headers = {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

# change this payload to your needs:
payload = {
    "sz": "1620825003874",
    "ez": "1620825063886",
    "wordlist": "life|think|can|got|too|what|land|earth|side|what|turn|between|book|car|quickly|not|leave|list|our|good|change|where|into|line|my|her|keep|other|such|say|not|her|soon|many|the|your|its|no|Indian|air|small|don't|second|city|different|sea|move|near|will|never|mean|there|such|also|something|spell|their|an|most|need|and|big|almost|miss|form|how|it's|add|group|let|stop|make|through|being|get|to|air|plant|around|try|just|face|men|eat|soon|great|work|very|good|city|move|this|much|to|idea|part|under|off|you|never|one|along|old|picture|being|let|might|now|people|went|example|even|old|family|begin|another|mile|great|Indian|second|us|home|did|thought|did|few|around|that|made|carry|hard|ask|talk|do|those|state|read|example|and|until|take|any|sentence|man|does|thing|carry|might|high|their|name|along|play|world|so|important|America|walk|this|to|it's|mother|large|feet|very|it|before|about|add|keep|use|run|away|old|every|out|down|might|you|find|small|still|idea|then|come|know|animal|Indian|thought|open|America|story|in|last|together|work|way|eat|hear|idea|tree|here|tell|may|work|food|he|should|way|place|be|question|important|next|just|thought|than|watch|country|leave|large|later|sound|until|give|but|use|left|as|animal|saw|here|day|large|be|water|want|question|way|father|over|said|of|face|land|began|something|house|group|line|word|are|turn|sea|form|sound|little|thing|but|by|boy|down|read|always|before|paper|into|leave|three|any|follow|side|has|through|at|white|walk|give|who|for|after|hard|world|hand|stop|want|kind|far|page|picture|again|well|thing|with|off|must|answer|right|have|about|got|run|found|air|play|will|world|go|or|almost|too|without|light|river|put|study|turn|oil|day|may|soon|without|or|where|mother|we|hear|is|through|watch|car|enough|close|cut|your|time|being|car|point|from|mo",
    "user_input": "life think got too what what land earth side what turn between book car quickly no leave list our good change where into line my her keep other such say her sonn many the your its no no Indioan air small don't second ",
    "backspace_counter": "5",
    "afk_timer": "1",
    "speedtest_id": "1",
    "mode": "",
}

data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload, headers=headers).json()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data["result"], "html.parser")

# print some data:
for row in soup.select("tr"):
    print(row.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```

Prints:

```
33 WPM (words per minute)
Keystrokes ( 163 | 55 ) 218
Accuracy 73.09%
Correct words 31
Wrong words 12
Share on Facebook
```